# Get the value of contenteditable span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

So I have this span, that has a content editable attribute on it and when you hit the button post -- I want to get the value of that span, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Note: I really cannot change the span to a textbox or to a div or anything -- I just really need the value from that content editable span.

Here is the HTML:

```
<span id="thirdspan" contenteditable="true">Write context text here:</span>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
 color: black;
 font-family:'Roboto';
 outline: 0px solid transparent;
```

Here is the JS:

```
var bodytext = $('#thirdspan').text;
alert(bodytext);
```

Thanks so much to anyone who can help!

Comment: Should be `var bodytext = $('#thirdspan').text();` be sure you have jquery loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var bodytext = $('#thirdspan').text;
```

You should do:

```
var bodytext = $('#thirdspan').text();
```

because `.text` is a method, so it needs the `()` to call it

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You'll want `$('#thirdspan').text();`. Or `$('#thirdspan').html();`, since contenteditable allows editing html.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
var bodytext = $('#thirdspan').text();
```

Be sure you have jquery loaded